# Why round_date() returns error for some units?

Tags: r, lubridate

I try to round dates (POSIXlt object) to the nearest 5 minutes. I tried to use round_date() function and run into following situation:

```
> date
[1] "2012-11-01 15:41:00 EET"
> is.POSIXlt(date)
[1] TRUE
> round_date(date, "hour")
[1] "2012-11-01 16:00:00 EET"
> round_date(date, "min")
[1] "2012-11-01 15:41:00 EET"
> round_date(date, "5 mins")
Error in above - mid : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

It seems to work for second, minute, hour and day. All the other units listed in the examples return this error.

I followed the advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397806/round-date-not-working-for-a-specific-posixct-object) thread and specified tz, but this didn't change anything.

period() function seems to work fine:

```
> period("5 mins")
[1] "5M 0S"
```

The above example is for the sake of simplicity as this data is a part of data frame. I don't know if that is relevant, but I also tried to work around it using mutate and replace. That failed with

> x 'origin' must be supplied

Thanks!

EDIT

The problem was reproducible for POSIXlt objects. Bug report is submitted. Quick fix for my problem was:

```
> round_date(as.POSIXct(date), "5 mins")
[1] "2012-11-01 15:40:00 EET"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing a numeric modifier prior to one of the supported time units is not a supported option for the `round.POSIXt` function/method, at least it's not documented in the help page. Such a feature *is* supported for `seq.POSIXt` and `cut.POSIXt`, so I can certainly see why that might have been a reasonable assumption. You could get  that as a desired result by doing modulo division by the seconds equivalent of 5 mins and then ordinary multiplication by that amount, but you would of course need to reconvert to POSIXlt class. One of the gotcha's of `as.POSIXt.numeric` is that you do need to specify an "origin" which is typically "1970-01-01". (Seems to me that it ought to be a default assumption.)

Allan is correct in thinking that yet again I've been too hasty im my reading of a question. (It might have helped if I had seen something along the lines of:

```
library(lubridate)
```

[EDIT] My new guess is that this is something to do with Daylight-to-Standard Time switchover. I'm unable to replicate the error with:

```
x <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2009-08-03 12:01:59.23")
lubridate::round_date(x, "5 mins")
[1] "2009-08-03 12:00:00 UTC"
```

The EET DST-> Standard transition is

> Eastern European Time (EET), observed in countries including Bulgaria, Estonia, Finland, Greece, Latvia, Romania, Turkey, Ukraine.
> Daylight saving time starts at 03:00 local time, when clocks move forward to 04:00.

> The Daylight Saving Time (DST) period in Europe runs from 01:00 UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) on the last Sunday of March to 01:00 UTC on the last Sunday of October every year.

[Further EDIT]; Wrong again. And now I am able to cause the undesirable action. Advancing the hour beyond the 3-4 hour does not cure the problem when a "ymd_hms"-created vector is converted to `POSIXlt` class:

```
 x <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2012-11-01 15:41:00 EET",tz="EET")
 lubridate::round_date(x, "5 mins")
#[1] "2012-11-01 15:40:00 EET"

x <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2012-11-01 17:41:00 EET",tz="EET")
 lubridate::round_date(as.POSIXlt(x), "5 mins")
#Error in above - mid : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Could there be a bug in `pkg:lubridate` when operating on `POSIXlt` objects? There's no error operating on POSIXct objects:

```
lubridate::round_date(as.POSIXct(x), "5 mins")
[1] "2012-11-01 17:40:00 EET"
```

The way to report suspected bugs in R package is to run:

```
maintainer("lubridate")
#[1] "Vitalie Spinu <spinuvit@gmail.com>"
```

And send a report with a [MCVE].

Comment: I think the OP is referring to `round_date` from package `lubridate`, which does in fact support numeric modifiers. In fact, I cannot replicate the error since the code works as expected on my pc.

Comment: Thanks! The `isdst` attribute is 0. I changed it to 1 and got the same error again.

Comment: Right. It seems to only be returning this error with pure POSIXlt objects. Using POSIXct succeeds: `lubridate::round_date(as.POSIXct(x), "5 mins")` returns `[1] "2012-11-01 17:40:00 EET"`

Comment: Indeed! I also got expected behaviour using POSIXct.

Comment: I sent a reference to this question and the linked question to the maintainer of pkg:"lubridate".